# In a predictable period of time?

Tags: expressions

Can I say this:

> I have no plans to come back **in a predictable period of time?**

I mean I have no idea when I will be back, not within a period of time that I can predict. Does that make any sense? Is it correct in English?

Comment: I mean I have no idea when I will be back, not within a period of time that I  can predict. Does that make any sense?

Comment: It's grammatical. I'm not sure it's great phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

You can say it but I think the sentence is a little awkward as it is currently written. The use of the word 'plan' seems out of place here, you have of course prefixed it with 'no' - indicating the negative, but it just reads awkwardly.

Perhaps this would be better (if you will be returning but do not know when):

> I do not know when I will return.

Or this (if you do not know if you are going to return)

> I may return, I do not know when.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot find a citation for this that aligns with my own understanding, I would use the term "anytime soon". **E.g. "I have no plans to return anytime soon".**

Merriam-Webster [defines 'anytime soon'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anytime%20soon) as meaning:

> in the near future. *Things will not improve anytime soon.*

However, idiomatically its use in the sentence above would mean to me:

> There is a chance I will return, but it won't be in the short to medium term and I don't actually know when it *will* be

It can also have a slightly negative in tone, meaning 'I won't be coming back'

This may be a regional understanding.